# Generate JSON document using APEX_JSON

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Let me explain my scenario that you might understand better my issue. We have a requirement to create a JSON file from a set of tables with an specific format. I had the idea to use APEX_JSON because it is quite easy, but I am having a memory problem because the json document generates 5 million records. Actually the process works when I reduce the number of records by applying a rownum filter. However, when the query tries to create the json with the total amount of records, I got a PL-SQL numeric error, which basically behind is a memory overflow.

My original JSON query is as follows:

```
DECLARE
  l_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN

  for l_hdr_row in (select FILENAME, REPORT_DATE, DOMAINCODE, LEGALENTITYCODE from RDM_OUT.JSON_NKEY_REP_HDR where DOMAINCODE = '00001') 
  loop
  
     APEX_JSON.INITIALIZE_CLOB_OUTPUT;
     APEX_JSON.OPEN_OBJECT;
     APEX_JSON.OPEN_OBJECT(l_hdr_row.FILENAME);
     
     APEX_JSON.OPEN_OBJECT;
     APEX_JSON.WRITE('Date',l_hdr_row.REPORT_DATE);
     APEX_JSON.WRITE('DomainCode',l_hdr_row.DOMAINCODE);
     APEX_JSON.WRITE('LegalEntityCode',l_hdr_row.LEGALENTITYCODE);
     APEX_JSON.OPEN_ARRAY('Keys');
     
     FOR dtl IN (SELECT NATIVEKEY, MASTERKEY, ENDDATE
               FROM RDM_OUT.JSON_NKEY_REP_DTL  DTL
               WHERE DTL.FILENAME = l_hdr_row.FILENAME) LOOP
     
               APEX_JSON.OPEN_OBJECT;
               APEX_JSON.WRITE('NativeKey',dtl.NATIVEKEY);
               APEX_JSON.WRITE('MasterKey',dtl.MASTERKEY);
               APEX_JSON.WRITE('EndDate',dtl.ENDDATE);
               APEX_JSON.CLOSE_OBJECT;
     END LOOP;
     APEX_JSON.CLOSE_ARRAY;
     APEX_JSON.CLOSE_OBJECT;
     APEX_JSON.CLOSE_ALL;
    
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(APEX_JSON.GET_CLOB_OUTPUT);
     APEX_JSON.FREE_OUTPUT;  
  end loop;
END;
/
```

The first loop actually only recovers one row, which is treated in the second loop, where I got the 5,5 million records for the first and only occurrence in the first loop. I tried to use JSON_OBJECT and JSON_ARRAY but I cannot get the same output format that APEX_JSON is giving me.

I am using Oracle 12.2 so I cannot have the improvements of some of the JSON functions have in 18c and 19c.

Let me show you what I go with my original query using APEX_JSON

```
SQL> set serveroutput on size unlimited echo on timing on
SQL> DECLARE
  2    l_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  3    4
  5    for l_hdr_row in (select FILENAME, REPORT_DATE, DOMAINCODE, LEGALENTITYCODE from RDM_OUT.JSON_NKEY_REP_HDR where DOMAINCODE = '00001')
  loop

  6    7    8       APEX_JSON.INITIALIZE_CLOB_OUTPUT;
  9       APEX_JSON.OPEN_OBJECT;
 10       APEX_JSON.OPEN_OBJECT(l_hdr_row.FILENAME);
 11
     APEX_JSON.OPEN_OBJECT;
 12   13       APEX_JSON.WRITE('Date',l_hdr_row.REPORT_DATE);
     APEX_JSON.WRITE('DomainCode',l_hdr_row.DOMAINCODE);
 14   15       APEX_JSON.WRITE('LegalEntityCode',l_hdr_row.LEGALENTITYCODE);
     APEX_JSON.OPEN_ARRAY('Keys');
 16   17
     FOR dtl IN (SELECT NATIVEKEY, MASTERKEY, ENDDATE
               FROM RDM_OUT.JSON_NKEY_REP_DTL  DTL
 18   19   20                 WHERE DTL.FILENAME = l_hdr_row.FILENAME and rownum < 5 ) LOOP

               APEX_JSON.OPEN_OBJECT;
               APEX_JSON.WRITE('NativeKey',dtl.NATIVEKEY);
 21   22   23   24                 APEX_JSON.WRITE('MasterKey',dtl.MASTERKEY);
               APEX_JSON.WRITE('EndDate',dtl.ENDDATE);
 25                 APEX_JSON.CLOSE_OBJECT;
     END LOOP;
 26   27   28       APEX_JSON.CLOSE_ARRAY;
     APEX_JSON.CLOSE_OBJECT;
     APEX_JSON.CLOSE_ALL;

 29   30   31   32       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(APEX_JSON.GET_CLOB_OUTPUT);
     APEX_JSON.FREE_OUTPUT;
  end loop;
END;
 33   34   35   36  /
{
"RTTA_00013_20190831_00001_00055_NKEY":{
{
"Date":"2019-08-31"
,"DomainCode":"
00001"
,"LegalEntityCode":"00055"
,"Keys":[
{
"NativeKey":"85430299"
,"MasterKey
":"01483175470"
,"EndDate":"9999-12-31"
}
,{
"NativeKey":"33227843"
,"MasterKey"
:"329401533000001934"
,"EndDate":"9999-12-31"
}
,{
"NativeKey":"42565570"
,"Mast
erKey":"01500329780"
,"EndDate":"9999-12-31"
}
,{
"NativeKey":"98536882"
,"Maste
rKey":"01502416501"
,"EndDate":"9999-12-31"
}
]
}
}
}
```

My questions are the following:

1. Is there a better way to do what I am doing with APEX_JSON ? Perhaps I can use BULK COLLECT with limit somehow ?
2. How can I got the same result and format with JSON_OBJECT and JSON_ARRAY ? I tried but I don't get the same output format.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I came up with my own solution that works. I changed to BULK COLLECT, and now the process works perfectly. Here you can see how the code looks like now:

```
 DECLARE
        c_limit   CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 50000; 
        CURSOR nkey_cur (v_filename in varchar2) IS SELECT * FROM RDM_OUT.JSON_NKEY_REP_DTL DTL where DTL.FILENAME = v_filename ;
        TYPE tbl_Nativekey IS TABLE OF RDM_OUT.JSON_NKEY_REP_DTL%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
        var_Nativekey tbl_Nativekey;
        PROCEDURE print_clob_to_output (p_clob IN CLOB)  
         IS  
           l_offset     INT := 1;  
         BEGIN  
            loop  
                exit when l_offset > dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob);  
                dbms_output.put_line( dbms_lob.substr( p_clob, 255, l_offset ) );  
                l_offset := l_offset + 255;  
            end loop;  
         END print_clob_to_output;
    BEGIN
      for l_hdr_row in (select FILENAME, REPORT_DATE, DOMAINCODE, LEGALENTITYCODE from RDM_OUT.JSON_NKEY_REP_HDR where DOMAINCODE = '00001' )
         loop
      
         APEX_JSON.INITIALIZE_CLOB_OUTPUT;
        -- APEX_JSON.OPEN_OBJECT;
        -- APEX_JSON.OPEN_OBJECT(l_hdr_row.FILENAME);
         
         APEX_JSON.OPEN_OBJECT;
         APEX_JSON.WRITE('Date',l_hdr_row.REPORT_DATE);
         APEX_JSON.WRITE('DomainCode',l_hdr_row.DOMAINCODE);
         APEX_JSON.WRITE('LegalEntityCode',l_hdr_row.LEGALENTITYCODE);
         APEX_JSON.OPEN_ARRAY('Keys');
         
         OPEN nkey_cur(l_hdr_row.FILENAME);
         
       LOOP
          FETCH nkey_cur BULK COLLECT INTO var_Nativekey LIMIT c_limit;
          EXIT WHEN var_Nativekey.COUNT = 0;  
             FOR i IN var_Nativekey.FIRST..var_Nativekey.LAST LOOP
                   APEX_JSON.OPEN_OBJECT;
                   APEX_JSON.WRITE('NativeKey',var_Nativekey(i).NATIVEKEY);
                   APEX_JSON.WRITE('MasterKey',var_Nativekey(i).MASTERKEY);
                   APEX_JSON.WRITE('EndDate',var_Nativekey(i).ENDDATE);
                   APEX_JSON.CLOSE_OBJECT;
             END LOOP;
         END LOOP;
     
         CLOSE nkey_cur;
         
         APEX_JSON.CLOSE_ARRAY;
         APEX_JSON.CLOSE_OBJECT;
         APEX_JSON.CLOSE_ALL;
        
         PRINT_CLOB_TO_OUTPUT(p_clob => APEX_JSON.GET_CLOB_OUTPUT);
         APEX_JSON.FREE_OUTPUT;  
      end loop;
    END;
    /
```

I was not able to get the same format using SQL/JSON functions, so I decided to convert the code I was using to get benefit of BULK COLLECT. I also modified how the clob should be printed in the output to avoid problems with the buffer:

```
SQL> host cat JSON_00001_NKEY.sql
spool &1

DECLARE
    c_limit   CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 10000; -- EXAMPLE of LIMIT
    CURSOR nkey_cur (v_filename in varchar2) IS SELECT * FROM RDM_OUT.JSON_NKEY_REP_DTL DTL where DTL.FILENAME = v_filename ;
    TYPE tbl_Nativekey IS TABLE OF RDM_OUT.JSON_NKEY_REP_DTL%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    var_Nativekey tbl_Nativekey;
        PROCEDURE print_clob_to_output (p_clob IN CLOB)
         IS
           l_offset     INT := 1;
         BEGIN
                loop
                        exit when l_offset > dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob);
                        dbms_output.put_line( dbms_lob.substr( p_clob, 255, l_offset ) );
                        l_offset := l_offset + 255;
                end loop;
         END print_clob_to_output;
BEGIN
  for l_hdr_row in (select FILENAME, REPORT_DATE, DOMAINCODE, LEGALENTITYCODE from RDM_OUT.JSON_NKEY_REP_HDR where DOMAINCODE = '00001' )
     loop

     APEX_JSON.INITIALIZE_CLOB_OUTPUT;

     APEX_JSON.OPEN_OBJECT;
     APEX_JSON.WRITE('Date',l_hdr_row.REPORT_DATE);
     APEX_JSON.WRITE('DomainCode',l_hdr_row.DOMAINCODE);
     APEX_JSON.WRITE('LegalEntityCode',l_hdr_row.LEGALENTITYCODE);
     APEX_JSON.OPEN_ARRAY('Keys');

     OPEN nkey_cur(l_hdr_row.FILENAME);

   LOOP
      FETCH nkey_cur BULK COLLECT INTO var_Nativekey LIMIT c_limit;
      EXIT WHEN var_Nativekey.COUNT = 0;
         FOR i IN var_Nativekey.FIRST..var_Nativekey.LAST LOOP
               APEX_JSON.OPEN_OBJECT;
               APEX_JSON.WRITE('NativeKey',var_Nativekey(i).NATIVEKEY);
               APEX_JSON.WRITE('MasterKey',var_Nativekey(i).MASTERKEY);
               APEX_JSON.WRITE('EndDate',var_Nativekey(i).ENDDATE);
               APEX_JSON.CLOSE_OBJECT;
         END LOOP;
     END LOOP;

     CLOSE nkey_cur;

     APEX_JSON.CLOSE_ARRAY;
     APEX_JSON.CLOSE_OBJECT;
     APEX_JSON.CLOSE_ALL;

     PRINT_CLOB_TO_OUTPUT(p_clob => APEX_JSON.GET_CLOB_OUTPUT);
     APEX_JSON.FREE_OUTPUT;
  end loop;
END;
/

spool off

exit

SQL> set serveroutput off
SQL> set timing on
SQL> @JSON_00001_NKEY.sql test.json
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:02:33.89
```

I guess there must be an option using SQL/JSON, but I honestly believe that APEX_JSON provides a quite easy API. To be careful with memory overflow or performance issues, BULK COLLECT might be a good approach.

Comment: Adding the LIMIT to your BULK COLLECT makes it even better. Just pointing it out for those who haven't used BULK COLLECT much.